# 1 to many relationship in Parse.com using Python Restful API

Tags: python, api, parse-platform

I am using Parse to build my database.

I have two tables: `Article` & `Comment`. Where `Article` has one or many `Comments`

I am using Parse Resful API `[ParsePy][1]` to add items

```
from parse_rest.datatypes import Object

class Article(Object):
    pass
class Comment(Object):
    pass

articleItem = Article(title='Test', author='John Doe')
articleItem.save() # we have to save it before it can be referenced
```

I don't know how to achieve this 1:N relationship, Can anyone show a way to make this:

Comment: Is that the full question?  It looks like you're about to display an example.

Comment: Yes ! the question is how to implement 1 to many relationship using Parse.Com

Answer (score 0):

```
from parse_rest.datatypes import Object

class Article(Object):
    pass
class Comment(Object):
    pass

articleItem = Article(title='Test', author='John Doe')
# for example, you get data from json
comments = []
for data in incoming_json['comments']:
    # Don't know why, but this cannot working [Comments(**data).save() for data in incoming_json['comments]]
    comment = Comments(**data)
    comment.save()
    comments.append(comment)
articleItem.comments = comments
articleItem.save() # we have to save it before it can be referenced
```

If you get query, you will receive:

```
[<Comments:v6PvbsPbQT>, <Comments:V5JpqPRuS6>, <Comments:HNocXqmUeJ>,]
```